# C# HtmlAgilityPack Relative node selection. Xpath being very, very naughty

Tags: c#, xpath

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="orders">
 <div>
   <div>
    <div>InnerText</div>


HtmlNode parentNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"orders\"]");
HtmlNode childNode = parentNode.SelectSingleNode("/div/div/div");
string myStr = childNode.InnerText; // should be "InnerText", no?
```

This seems logical to me but I'm throwing NullReferenceExceptions on myStr. Is it my xpath notation or am I misunderstanding the hierarchy?

Comment: I think The xpath for your childNode is wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative XPath should never begin with `/`. By starting with `/`, the XPath will be considered relative to the root document node (in other words, absolute instead of relative to the context element). Since the root element of your HTML document is not a `div`, `/div` would expectedly return no matching element.

You should use `./` instead :

```
HtmlNode childNode = parentNode.SelectSingleNode("./div/div/div");
```

or just start with `div` directly since `child::` axis is the default when no explicit axis is mentioned :

```
HtmlNode childNode = parentNode.SelectSingleNode("div/div/div");
```